# Plot function of kondo resonance model specific heat

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I've been trying to plot the expression for the specific heat, as derived [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0375960175903862). The function is

$$ C/T= \frac{\Delta}{\pi T^2}-\frac{2 k_\mathrm{B}}{T} Re \Bigg(\frac{\Delta+i g \mu_B H}{\left( 2\pi k_\mathrm{B} T \right)^2} \left( 4 \psi\prime\left( 1 + \frac{\Delta+i g \mu_B H}{\left( \pi k_\mathrm{B} T \right)^2} \right) - \psi\prime\left( 1 + \frac{\Delta+i g \mu_B H}{\left( 2\pi k_\mathrm{B} T \right)^2} \right)\right) \Bigg),$$

where $\psi\prime(x)$ is the derivative of the digamma function, $H$ is the applied field, $g$=2 is the landé factor and $\Delta$ is the resonance width, which at sufficiently low fields can be identified as $\Delta=k_\mathrm{B} T_\mathrm{K}$.

A plot of the function at various fields is found [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-06782-1).

I tried to calculate this function in matlab. I calculated the derivate numerically, the rest is quite straight forward. However, my function looks wrong since it derivates for low temperatures. Also a collaborator has tried to plot the function and got the same result. We implemented it in different ways and independently of each other, so this is a sign for the correct implementation. Now I am already suspecting that there is something wrong with the constants or units (I doublechecked it of course) or some other minor mistake. Can anyone help me further with this?

This is my code:

```
function Kondo_model(T_K)
close all;
%T=[1E-5:1E-2:4];
T=logspace(-1,1,200); %K
k_B=1.380649E-23;  %J/K
%T_K=4;             %K
Delta=T_K*k_B;     %J
R=8.314462;        %J / (mol K)
g=2;               %1
B=1E-3;            %Vs/m^2
H=B/(4*pi*1E-7)    %A/m
mu_B=9.274E-24;    %J/T
N_A=R/k_B;         %1/mol

arg1=1+(Delta+1i*g*mu_B*H)./(pi*k_B.*T);    %Abbreviations
arg2=1+(Delta+1i*g*mu_B*H)./(2*pi*k_B.*T);

Fkt1=psi(arg1);                         %digamma functions
Fkt2=psi(arg2);

%figure();
%plot(x, psi(x)); %Psi is Digamma

%figure();
%plot(x, gradient(psi(x))); %Derivative of Psi

leng=size(T);                   %number of numerical points


Pstrich1=zeros(1,leng(2));      %initialize 0-vector of psi'
Pstrich2=zeros(1,leng(2));

for i = 1:(leng(2)-1)           %calculate derivative with differential approach
Pstrich1(i)=( Fkt1(i+1) - Fkt1(i) ) / ( arg1(i+1)-arg1(i) );    
Pstrich1(i)=Pstrich1(i)*(-(arg1(i)-1)/T(i)^2);      %due to chain rule

Pstrich2(i)=( Fkt2(i+1) - Fkt2(i) ) / ( arg2(i+1)-arg2(i) );
Pstrich2(i)=Pstrich2(i)*(-(arg2(i)-1)/T(i)^2);      %due to chain rule
%display('yo');
end

bracket=4.*Pstrich1-Pstrich2;

CoverT=(Delta./(pi.*T.^2))-( ((2*k_B)./T).*real(((arg2-1).^2).*bracket ));
CoverT=CoverT*N_A;

figure();
plot(T, CoverT);
%semilogy(T, N_A*CoverT, "linewidth", 5);
axis([0.4 10 0 20]);
%plot(x, -gradient(psi(einer./x))./x.^2);

display('Fin.');
clear all;

endfunction
```

Thanks for your help!

weylso